# Perform multiple operations in a single groupby call with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to produce a summary dataframe after grouping by date. I want to have a column that shows the mean of a given column as it is and the mean of that same column after filtering for instances that are greater than 0. I figured out how I can do this (below), but it requires doing two separate `groupby` calls, renaming the columns, and then joining them back together.  I fell like one should be able to do this all in one call.  I was trying to use `eval` to do this but kept getting an error and being told to use `apply`, that I couldn't use `eval` on a groupby object.

Code which gets me what I want but doesn't seem very efficient:

```
# Sample data

data = pd.DataFrame(
          {"year" : [2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014],
           "month" : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
           "day": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           "delay": [0, -4, 50, -60, 9, 10]})

subset = (data
          .groupby(['year', 'month', 'day'])['delay']
          .mean()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns = {'delay' : 'avg_delay'})
         )

subset_1 = (data[data.delay > 0]
          .groupby(['year', 'month', 'day'])['delay']
          .mean()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns = {'delay' : 'avg_delay_pos'})
         )

combined = pd.merge(subset, subset_1, how='left', on=['year', 'month', 'day'])
combined

   year  month  day  avg_delay  avg_delay_pos
0  2013      1    1          0            NaN
1  2013      2    1         -4            NaN
2  2013      3    1         50           50.0
3  2014      1    1        -60            NaN
4  2014      2    1          9            9.0
5  2014      3    1         10           10.0
```

Comment: Usable sample data would make this so much easier to answer.  Read [mcve]

Comment: you could write your own function doing all the things togheter and use `apply`.

Comment: Probably `combined = data
          .groupby(['year', 'month', 'day'])['delay', 'pos']
          .mean()
          .reset_index().rename(columns = {'delay' : 'avg_delay', 'pos' : 'avg_delay_pos'})` could be enough. But I cannot be sure without some data...

Comment: Added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is specific to your problem, but you can do this using a single groupby call. To get "avg_delay_pos", you just have to remove negative (and zero) values.

```
df['delay_pos'] = df['delay'].where(df['delay'] > 0)

(df.filter(like='delay')
   .groupby(pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']]))
   .mean()
   .add_prefix('avg_'))                                                                                                                                 

            avg_delay  avg_delay_pos
2013-01-01          0            NaN
2013-02-01         -4            NaN
2013-03-01         50           50.0
2014-01-01        -60            NaN
2014-02-01          9            9.0
2014-03-01         10           10.0
```

---

**Breakdown**

`where` is used to mask values that are not positive.

```
df['delay_pos'] = df['delay'].where(df['delay'] > 0)
# df['delay'].where(df['delay'] > 0)                                                                                                  

0     NaN
1     NaN
2    50.0
3     NaN
4     9.0
5    10.0
Name: delay, dtype: float64
```

Next, extract the delay columns we want to group on,

```
df.filter(like='delay')                                                                                                             

   delay  delay_pos
0      0        NaN
1     -4        NaN
2     50       50.0
3    -60        NaN
4      9        9.0
5     10       10.0
```

Then perform a `groupby` on the date,

```
_.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])).mean()

            delay  delay_pos
2013-01-01      0        NaN
2013-02-01     -4        NaN
2013-03-01     50       50.0
2014-01-01    -60        NaN
2014-02-01      9        9.0
2014-03-01     10       10.0
```

Where `pd.to_datetime` is used to convert the year/month/day columns into a single datetime column, it's more efficient to group on a single column than multiple.

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])                                                                                        

0   2013-01-01
1   2013-02-01
2   2013-03-01
3   2014-01-01
4   2014-02-01
5   2014-03-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The final `.add_prefix('avg_')` add prefix "_avg" to the result.

---

An alternative way to do this if you want separate year/month/day columns would be

```
df['delay_pos'] = df['delay'].where(df['delay'] > 0)
df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day']).mean().add_prefix('avg_').reset_index()

   year  month  day  avg_delay  avg_delay_pos
0  2013      1    1          0            NaN
1  2013      2    1         -4            NaN
2  2013      3    1         50           50.0
3  2014      1    1        -60            NaN
4  2014      2    1          9            9.0
5  2014      3    1         10           10.0
```

Comment: I guess what I'm learning is these types of operations can't be done in one line.

Comment: @BenG PS, you can do anything you want in a single line. My second method can be reduced to `df.assign(delay_pos=df['delay'].where(df['delay'] > 0)).groupby(['year', 'month', 'day']).mean().add_prefix('avg_').reset_index()` which is a single line. I've expanded it into two for clarity. It isn't my place to say this but I feel like you've thrown away your bounty :(

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use the following code:

```
>>> data['avg_delay'] = data.pop('delay')
>>> data['avg_delay_pos'] = data.loc[data['avg_delay'].gt(0), 'avg_delay']
>>> data
   day  month  year  avg_delay  avg_delay_pos
0    1      1  2013          0            NaN
1    1      2  2013         -4            NaN
2    1      3  2013         50           50.0
3    1      1  2014        -60            NaN
4    1      2  2014          9            9.0
5    1      3  2014         10           10.0
>>>
```

Explanation:

- I first remove the `delay` column, and assign it to the new name of `avg_delay`, so I am virtually renaming the name of `delay` to `avg_delay`.
- Then I create a new column called `avg_delay_pos`, which first uses `loc` to get the values greater than zero, and since the index doesn't reset, so it will make the indexes that are greater than zero to the values of `avg_delay`, and the others won't contain any assignments, that said they will be `NaN` as you expected.

Comment: I guess what I'm learning is that these types of operations can't be done in one line.

Comment: @BenG How and why is this correct? The only reason you get the same answer as the groupby solution is because the calendar dates are unique in the _sample data_. I thought this was obvious.